# AWS Cloudformation APIGateway Encountered unsupported property IntegrationResponses when trying to set static header value

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, devops

I am trying to set my Header Mappings on the Method Execution of an AWS APIGateway using Cloudformation.

Here is what I want my end state to be:
[image]

Here is the Cloudformation JSON Template snippet I am trying to use:

```
   "AlertDetailMock": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
  "Properties": {
    "RestApiId": {
      "Ref": "RestApi"
    },
    "ResourceId": {
      "Ref": "AlertDetailResource"
    },
    "HttpMethod": "OPTIONS",
    "AuthorizationType": "NONE",
    "Integration": {
      "Type": "MOCK",
      "RequestTemplates": {
        "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
      }
    },
    "IntegrationResponses": [
      {
        "ResponseTemplates": {
          "application/json": ""
        },
        "ResponseParameters": {
          "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "\\'*\\'",
          "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "\\'GET,OPTIONS\\'",
          "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "\\'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token\\'"
        },
        "StatusCode": 200
      }
    ],
    "MethodResponses": [
      {
        "ResponseModels": {
          "application/json": {
            "Ref": "AlertDetailsModel"
          }
        },
        "ResponseParameters": {
          "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
          "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": true,
          "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": true
        },
        "StatusCode": 200
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

When I run the template I get the following error:

```
    14:23:06 UTC-0400   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ApiGateway::Method AlertDetailMock Encountered unsupported property IntegrationResponses
```

The documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html) says:

> Static value  'STATIC_VALUE'. The STATIC_VALUE is a string literal and must be enclosed within a pair of single quotes.

I have tried every combination of escape that I could think of to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues with your given template.

The first one is, that the `IntegrationResponses` element needs to be inside the `Integration` element.

The second issue is related to the escaping, you actually do not need to escape single quotes in JSON. So just placing the value inside is fine.

```
    "AlertDetailMock": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {
                "Ref": "RestApi"
            },
            "ResourceId": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["RestApi", "RootResourceId"]
            },
            "HttpMethod": "OPTIONS",
            "AuthorizationType": "NONE",
            "Integration": {
                "Type": "MOCK",
                "RequestTemplates": {
                    "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
                },

                "IntegrationResponses": [{
                    "ResponseTemplates": {
                        "application/json": ""
                    },
                    "ResponseParameters": {
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'GET,OPTIONS'",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                    },
                    "StatusCode": 200
                }]
            },
            "MethodResponses": [{
                "ResponseParameters": {
                    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
                    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": true,
                    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": true
                },
                "StatusCode": 200
            }]
        }
    }
```